# How to change button caption dynamically with BurntToast?

Tags: powershell, notifications, toast, windows-11

I use `BurntToast` module in order to throw toast notifications in Windows 11.

Here are my codes:

```
$Data =
@{
    Line1Data = 'Line 1'
    Line2Data = 'Line 2'
    Line3Data = 'Line 3'
    StatusData = ''
    TitleData = 'The file is being downloaded...'
    ValueData = 15/100
}

$Button1 = New-BTButton -Arguments 'stackoverflow://pause' -Content 'Pause' -ActivationType Protocol
$Button2 = New-BTButton -Arguments 'stackoverflow://cancel' -Content 'Cancel' -ActivationType Protocol
$ProgressBar = New-BTProgressBar -Status 'StatusData' -Title 'TitleData' -Value 'ValueData'

New-BurntToastNotification -Button $Button1, $Button2 -ProgressBar $ProgressBar -Text 'Line1Data', 'Line2Data', 'Line3Data' -DataBinding $Data -UniqueIdentifier 'example'
```

Here is my notification:

[First Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWOV1.png)

When I click `Pause` button, its caption should be changed to `Resume` and its argument should be changed to `stackoverflow://resume`.

Here is the screenshot which describes what I want:

[Second Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQfeF.png)

PS: This notification is not updated from first one. I have created fresh notification in order to show.

So, how can I achieve that?